# Change gtk+ file open dialog

Tags: linux, firefox, gtk

I’d like to change it for another that can resize picture on the preview, i.e. not only show a thumbnail of fixed size.

I know that this may require change of the toolkit in use, so which packages do I need to install/replace to make firefox show another file open dialog?

Comment: [For archlinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/firefox-kde-opensuse/) there is a patched version of FF for KDE. It works well if you are in KDE and like the stripped down version of dolphin/whatever it is, but unfortunately doesn't seem to change the file selector if you are not using KDE (as I currently am..)

Comment: @gandalf3 I’m not using neither Arch nor KDE. And I’m, honestly speaking, not very fond of idea of bloating my system with Qt just to install a file open dialog. When I posted the question I was thinking about choosing images, now I’m simply copying filename from a specialized image viewer, it’s better.