# Replacing of GTK+ file dialogs with KDE's via XDG portals not working (XFCE, Manjaro)

Tags: ubuntu, kde, manjaro, gtk, xdg

I'm stuck after trying and triple-checking everything from the most upvoted answer (from @ntninja) to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/944119/replace-gtk-file-dialog-with-alternative). I did this on two machines - Manjaro and an old Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

1. Installed the `xdg-desktop-portal-kde`.
2. Edited `/usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals/kde.portal` to add the value of `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: UseIn=KDE;XFCE`.
3. Added `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1` to `~/.pam_environment`.
4. Logged out and back in to apply these changes.

I always get the GTK file dialogs, in every app (Firefox, Thunderbird, gedit, [newest VScode](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/u0n233/visual_studio_code_now_supports_kde_file_picker/)), etc). It doesn't work under XFCE nor under KDE/plasma. (I'm aware of the differences regarding the xdg desktop portals).

The `"widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker"=1` from Firefox's `about:config` doesn't work either...

Can anybody direct me on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried setting `export GTK_USE_PORTAL=1` in `~/.profile` instead of in `~/.pam_environment`?

Comment: I did - to no avail. Same result. Is there some way to get to know, what goes wrong?

Comment: After a lot of googling a found a partial solution:
After killing 'xdg-desktop-portal-gtk' and  'xdg-desktop-portal' and running `/usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal-kde -p BGRx` in the terminal, KDE file dialogs are shown under Plasma, but mysteriously not under XFCE. 

ref. [https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg584480.html](https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg584480.html)

Answer (score 3):

At least on Fedora 36 KDE Plasma to get Plasma/KDE native file dialog In Thunderbird you have to:

- Open settings ->
- scroll to the bottom ->
- click on Config Editor ->
- search for: widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker
- Set the value to "1" (no quotes) from the default "2".

No need to prefix the program execution with any, above mentioned, environment variables.